# concatenar variável em link - javascript

Tags: javascript

Meu problema está na passagem de parâmetro no link, porque lá na página que recebe, está chegando como valor as variáveis ao invés dos valores.

Acredito que o problema esteja realmente na concatenação das variáveis na formação do link.

As variáveis serão números decimais ou inteiros.

```
var ins = 123.46;
var newcostumer = 456889; 

<script src="http://teste.testando.com.br/da.js?pagina=home&inst=ins&newcustomer=nc&id=123" async="async"> </script>
```

Comment: Ficou meio obscuro o que vc quer. Qual o objetivo afinal?

Comment: André, tem que melhorar a pergunta para que possamos ajudar. Da onde provém as variáveis? Copie e cole o código completo para entendimento. Esses valores estão em campos input hidden ou foram enviados por GET para essa página?

Comment: Veja se a resposta te ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `document.write` para construir a URL passando variáveis:

```
<script>
var ins = 123.46;
var newcostumer = 456889;
document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="http://teste.testando.com.br/da.js?pagina=home&inst='+ins+'&newcustomer='+newcostumer+'&id=123" async="async"> </scr'+'ipt>');
</script>
```

Note que foi preciso fazer duas concatenações `scr'+'ipt` para que o JavaScript não crie um script dentro do outro, resultando em erro.